# fantasy series about a village surrounded by fog/mist that teenage girl escapes through

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

Here are the pieces I remember. A girl lived in a society with strict rules, parents die and younger brother gets taken into the governing society and doesn't acknowledge sister. The governing body of elites have powers and so does the little brother. I think there is one female leader who is sympathetic to the orphans. The working class lives in trees? and work in a foundry? forging some kind of figurine. They escape into the outer world that the society doesn't believe exists through a deadly fog or mist. I read this I believe 7-8 years ago, not sure if it was a newer book or not but I don't believe it was really old. So I would say maybe 10-15 years ago.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: When did you read it, and do you know about how old the book is?

Comment: I read it probably 7-8 years ago. It wasn't a new release, but not an older book. So I would say 10 years ago or so.

Comment: Thank you. I updated information.

Comment: Just to let you know, you don't have to add "Edited" to the title. :) It shows up once one clicks in.

Comment: something else I remember, the older boys (older teen?) have to fight, become champions or something. The friend that escapes with the girl is one of the fighters, maybe won. and the boy he is supposed to fight is the classic bull type.

Comment: Brought to mind "Gathering Blue" and "Messenger", but it doesn't really fit.  Just a mention, as sometimes story-id questions conflate more than one story.  This has a teenage orphan girl and some other orphans (but I don't remember a  brother), a village that you "can't" leave because it is dangerous beyond (supposedly due to "Beasts"; I don't think there is a fog).  There are specific gifts and jobs for some.

Answer (score 3):

Could this be [Hidden](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18719280-hidden) by Megg Jensen (part of the [Dragonlands](https://www.goodreads.com/series/119260-dragonlands) series of books)?

> The mystery enshrouding Hutton’s Bridge is as impenetrable as the fog
>   that descended at its borders eighty years ago. Each year, three
>   villagers enter the mist searching for answers. No one ever returns.
>
> Then a dragon falls from the sky to the town square, dead—the first
>   glimpse of an outside world that has become nothing more than a fairy
>   tale to Hutton’s Bridge. Except to Tressa.
>
> Tressa grew up with Granna’s stories of the days before the fog fell.
>   When Granna dies, leaving Tressa without any family, Tressa ventures
>   into the fog herself, vowing to unravel the foul magic holding
>   Hutton’s Bridge captive.
>
> What she discovers beyond the fog endangers the lives of everyone she
>   loves.

[image]

Comment: no. i don't think so. I don't remember dragons and from what I remember, people were forbidden from entering the fog/mist until the girl/heroine escapes her village and fleas into the mist. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Some parts of your description sound like [Mistborn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mistborn) by Brandon Sanderson:

> The series primarily takes place in a region called the Final Empire on a world called Scadrial, where the sun and sky are red, vegetation is brown, and the ground is constantly being covered under black volcanic ashfalls. **Every night the land becomes covered in an unnatural mist or fog.**

Some other points that might be similar

> The **nobility has special abilities**
>
> At the beginning of the novel, the reader is **introduced to Vin**, the main female protagonist

Comment: I was going to suggest the same. There are differences, but they are like the most common mistakes made by folks asking YASID questions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this book is ***[The Finisher](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18282060-the-finisher)*** (2014) by David Baldacci! It's the first book in the *[Vega Jane](https://www.goodreads.com/series/137706-vega-jane)* series.

> Welcome to Wormwood: a place where curiosity is discouraged and no one has ever left.
>
> Until one girl, Vega Jane, discovers a map that suggests a mysterious world beyond the walls. A world with possibilities and creatures beyond her imagining.
>
> But she will be forced to fight for her freedom. And unravelling the truth may cost Vega her life.

I've been looking for this book for so long and all I could remember was the red circle cover and the girl sleeping in a tree and escaping fog around a town. Your description helped me remember more, and I found my book, which I believe is the same book you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you confirm any of the details of the question, like the fact that the protagonist has a brother, they are orphans, the brother is coopted into the ruling elite...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vega_Jane#The_Finisher mentions her brother being taken by the ruling elite if you want to pull a quote.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the book [*The Dark Hills Divide*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Hills_Divide): The Land of Elyon

> Inquisitive twelve-year-old Alexa Daley is spending another summer in the walled town of Bridewell. This year, she is set on solving the mystery of what lies beyond the walls. Legend says the walls were built to keep out an unnamed evil that lurks in the forests and The Dark Hills. But what exactly is it that the townspeople are so afraid of?
>
> As Alexa begins to unravel the truth, pushing beyond the protective barrier she's lived behind all her life, she discovers a strange and ancient enchantment -- and exposes a danger that could destroy everything she holds dear.
>
> <sub>https://www.patrickcarman.com/elyon</sub>